# Undefined method error?

Tags: php, joomla1.5

Joomla,I defined a method

```
function assignRef($key, &$val)
 {
  if (is_string($key) && substr($key, 0, 1) != '_')
  {
   $this->$key =& $val;
   return true;
  }

  return false;
 }
```

but when I cal that method I got an fatal error like:

`WWDatingController::assignRef()`

It is a Joomla base project. Please provide solution.

Comment: can you post the actual error message?

Comment: The actual eror Message is :
Fatal error: Call to undefined method WWDatingController::assignRef() in C:\wamp\www\joomla_se\components\com_wwdating\views\members\view.html.php on line 86

Answer (score 0):

More Code could be more useful.

I think your Problem is that you try to call the method statically instead of an normal call.

> Declaring class properties or methods as static makes them accessible
>   without needing an instantiation of the class. A property declared as
>   static can not be accessed with an instantiated class object (though a
>   static method can).

Make an Object of "WWDatingController" and try to access via

```
$object->assignRef();
```

or use the keyword "static" in the function declaration as follows

```
static function assignRef($key, &$val)
 {
  if (is_string($key) && substr($key, 0, 1) != '_')
  {
   $this->$key =& $val;
   return true;
  }

  return false;
 }
```

Because of the $this->key variable access i think you use an existing object, because you can not use $this in a static function. So answer 1 should be your solution.

For more Information about static in PHP use this [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)